# Activator UI is not responding

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

I try to use Play Webframework, but after installing the activator, creating a new play-java project, and started the `activtor ui` in commandline without errors I want to access the web UI but my browser don't get a response. There is also no error.

Has anybody an idea?

Thanks!